# Angular form select and input required

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want that the select and the input of the form is required. I tried to follow the tutorial on the angular website, however it doesn't work for me or I mixed something up. How can I fix it?

That's my html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm"  class="form-inline my-5 my-lg-0">
  <select #emoji class="textboxclass" type="text" placeholder="Emojy" aria-label="Post" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Emojy</option>
    <option value="angry" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/angry.png);">angry</option>
    <option value="bored" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/bored.png);">bored</option>
    <option value="confused" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/confused.png);">confused</option>
    <option value="embarrassed" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/embarrassed.png);">embarrassed</option>
    <option value="happy" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/happy.png);">happy</option>
    <option value="kissing" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/kissing.png);">kissing</option>
    <option value="unhappy" style="background-image:url(~assets/emoticons/png/unhappy.png);">unhappy</option>
  </select>
  <input #text id="postText" name="postText" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Write your Mood" aria-label="Post"
         formControlName="postText" required>
  <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['postText'].invalid && (angForm.controls['postText'].dirty
  || angForm.controls['postText'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['postText'].errors.required">Text required</div>
  </div>


</form>

<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="postMood(emoji.value, text.value)">Post </button >
```

And that is my component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {PostServiceService} from './post-service.service';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-service',
  templateUrl: './post-service.component.html',
  providers: [PostServiceService],
  styleUrls: ['./post-service.component.css']
})
export class PostServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  angForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private postService: PostServiceService, private  fb: FormBuilder) {this.createForm(); }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({postText: ['', Validators.required]});
  }

  postMood(emoji, text): void {
    this.postService.postMoods(emoji, text);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add emoji selection inside the form group.

```
this.angForm = this.fb.group({
  emoji: ['', Validators.required],
  postText: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Add `formControlName` to the select element

```
<select formControlName="emoji" ...>
```

Finally, add the disabled attribute to the button to prevent posting the mood without the required fields.

```
<button [disabled]="angForm.invalid" ...>
```

You can also drop the references on your elements and access form values like so

```
postMood() {
  const emoji = this.angForm.get('emoji').value;
  const text = this.angForm.get('postText').value;
  this.postService.postMoods(emoji, text);
  // Call to reset the form values
  this.angForm.reset();
}
```